# rspec does not load rails app subdirectories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have the following directory structure:

```
app
├── consumers
│   └── consumers
│       ├── foo.rb
...
```

I expect the `foo` consumer to be automatically included in the rails `autoload_paths` but when I look at the config in the spec:

```
MyApp::Application.config.autoload_paths
=> [#<Pathname:/home/myapp/lib>]
```

Any idea what's going on?

Explicitly adding the directory solves the issue:

`config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/consumers')`

Answer (score 1):

Since this `app/consumers` isn't a default load path, it won't be set unless you explicitly specify it in `application.rb`. Are you sure `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/consumers')` is present in `application.rb`?

Comment: all subdirectories under `app` are supposed to be automatically added in the autoloads_path since rails 4

Answer (score 0):

You can access a list of all the autoload_paths (both explicitly added in `config/application.rb` and the ones added by the Rails themselves by default), by calling `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths`.

`MyApp::Application.config.autoload_paths` will only contain a set of paths that have been defined in `config/application.rb`. These paths actually get [prepended into a the default set of paths](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L566) defined by rails during the initialization.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this! However I'm surprise that my `app/consumer` folder is not in the `autoload_paths` already as it should https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.6/railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb#L42

Comment: If you run `bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` from command line, is `app/consumer` folder included in the list? Also if you want to access the paths that are initialized by the code you linked, you need run `Rails.application.paths` in the console.

Comment: If you need more information on how autoloading and reloading works in Rails, I wholeheartedly recommend the Rails Guides chapter on the topic http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html